# Getting an error "cd: '/Users/x/Downloads/' is a rotten symlink" in Fish shell

Tags: shell, fish

Today I logged onto my machine and tried to `cd ~/Downloads`, but my shell (Fish) just returns the error `cd: '/Users/x/Downloads/' is a rotten symlink` without any further information.

It seems to originate from Fish's `builtin_cd` function call [here](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/src/builtin_cd.cpp#L112), however I can't tell what the reason is since my `Downloads` directory is not symlinked.

I'm able to `cd` into any other directory just fine and I'm able to access `Downloads` through MacOS's UI (Finder) so I don't think the directory data has been corrupted.

Does anyone know what the cause of this error could be and/or how to fix it?

edit: I've already tried reinstalling `Fish` from my package manager (homebrew), to no avail.

Comment: This feels like it isn't *quite* a programming question, since it's about a built-in function in Fish :-).  That, and I think you're more likely to get an answer on (probably) the [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or (perhaps) [Super User](https://superuser.com).  Personally I'd recommend deleting it here and asking it on the Unix/Linux site.  Recommend adding the *macos* tag as well when you repost.  You might also try the Fish shell subreddit ([r/fishshell](https://www.reddit.com/r/fishshell/)).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your terminal app is forbidden from accessing the Downloads directory. You can fix it like so:

1. Open Security and Privacy preference pane
2. Click on the Privacy tab
3. Select "Files and Folders" in the side bar
4. Find your terminal app, and ensure that the Downloads directory is checked for it

You'll have to relaunch the terminal before it can get access.

Comment: d'oh. I'm not sure how that even happened since I never changed any terminal permissions, but thanks!

Comment: I experienced the same symptom and the cause for me was doing a `sudo port upgrade outdated`. I imagine doing that or a similar `brew` command may be the  cause though I'm not sure why that would cause the terminal itself to lose permissions that it clearly once had. 

Same fix as described above fixed it for me, just providing some more context.

Comment: I am also surprised the privacy settings changed on my computer without explicit edition.